# Check if a set is an affine subvariety

Tags: geometry

I have the following :   $A=\{(x_1,x_2,x_3)\in\mathbb{R}^{3}:2x_{1}-x_{2}+x_{3}-2=0\}$, and I need to check if this is an affine subvariety .

I am having trouble understanding affine geometry, so I don't really know how to start and what I am supposed to do. Is there a general approach on how to check these things? Also, is $\mathbb{R}^3$ considered the affine space, and is there a difference between affine subspace/variety?